# How to select multiple lines for non matching selections?

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext

I'm working with some text in Sublime (Markdown) and I need to convert the following to table.
How can I enable my cursor on lines 1 through 8 without `CMD` clicking each line?

> ```
> 1 $11,670 $14,580 $13,420
> 2 $15,730 $19,660 $18,090
> 3 $19,790 $24,730 $22,760
> 4 $23,850 $29,820 $27,430
> 5 $27,910 $34,900 $32,100
> 6 $31,970 $39,980 $36,770
> 7 $36,030 $45,060 $41,440
> 8 $40,090 $50,140 $46,110
> ```

So that I can do this:

```
| 1 | $11,670 | $14,580 | $13,420 |
| 2 | $15,730 | $19,660 | $18,090 |
| 3 | $19,790 | $24,730 | $22,760 |
| 4 | $23,850 | $29,820 | $27,430 |
| 5 | $27,910 | $34,900 | $32,100 |
| 6 | $31,970 | $39,980 | $36,770 |
| 7 | $36,030 | $45,060 | $41,440 |
| 8 | $40,090 | $50,140 | $46,110 |
```

By "enable my cursor" on multiple lines I mean this: (see the blue)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the entire block of text with your mouse, then press  Ctrl+Shift+L on PC, or Command+Shift+L on OS X.

Or, if you want to stay away from the mouse completely, you can put your cursor at the beginning of the first line and press Ctrl+L on PC or Command+L on Mac to add additional lines to your selection, then press Ctrl+Shift+L on PC, or Command+Shift+L on OS X to edit those lines.

Lastly, if you prefer using your mouse instead of using keyboard shortcuts, then the answer @MattDMo gave is perfect.

Comment: You should also note that this command is available via `Selection -> Split into Lines` as well.

Comment: @MattDMo my mistake I tried: `Expand selection to line` I completely skipped passed Split into lines...